# Deployed to GitHub Pages, got an unexpected token?

Tags: javascript, json, github, github-pages

I've just deployed a simple website to GitHub Pages.
What is supposed to happen is that when a user types any relevant characters they get a list of relevant states and other information which is filtered from a JSON file. There seems to be an error with the JSON file being that there is an unexpected token '<' but I can't seem to fins any error with the JSON file. It works on my local environment with VSCode and Live Server but not when deployed.

[What's supposed to happen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uxp1K.png)

[What happens when deployed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sNTh0.png)

[Repository](https://github.com/sampraslee/Malaysia-State-Capital-Lookup)

Thanks for reading!

Comment: can you click directly on the get link of states.json and post the result here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the url to: https://sampraslee.github.io/Malaysia-State-Capital-Lookup/data/states.json

It should work

Comment: Thanks! This worked though I'm not too sure why? Since it's being deployed from Github why do I have to change the URL to fetch the data?

Comment: U must always refer to url and not relative path when using ajax calls